# How do I access a local directory inside Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, local, remote-desktop

I have some files and a script that I run in an elevated session on someone's desktop, and I do it because there are multiple steps involving copying folders into protected areas and messing with the registry. To accomplish this, I use `Invoke-Command`. The credentials I provide allow me to do so, but I have encountered an issue.

The script is in the same folder as files I want to copy. When I get that script's location, it gives me the wrong directory.

I want `c:\Users\TheLocalUser\Files`, but instead, I get
`c:\Users\TheCredentialsIProvided\Files`.

Because of this, my script cannot technically find the files I wish to copy. How do I reference these files stored on someone's computer using my script's location?

If that isn't possible, is there a better method out there?

Comment: how  so you retriev the script location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use arbitrary directories in user directories but rather have a centralized location for your script. If you need to find the user directory let script ask for the username if you can't design a process that allows for execution from within the user context. For instance, as you are running Invoke-Command with credentials, you could let the user start the script which would mean the home of the user would be what you expect.

Comment: I think I should specify more about how weird my situation is: I had these files on a network drive(but I couldn't create a psdrive to it,) I tried to create a drive to those network folders on the desktop(but the company didnt give me permission to do so,) and so I ultimately have people copy these files over and go from there. In fact, I remote into this person's desktop, download these files for them, then run the powershell script.

This script mostly just fixes an Addin for Outlook, but with how this company's policies are setup, I am really struggling for a clean solution...

Comment: (charlimit) Ultimately I use Invoke-Command as a means to get into the CDrive and Registry without creating temporary PSDrives, for both of these things cannot be accessed by regular users, you must use elevated credentials. So I figured having this script on their desktop, then creating an elevated session using my own, would bypass any issues I was having connecting to these drives and moving things into them without issues. I am new to powershell in general, but this is possibly the 5th attempt I've made trying to get files to move into someone's Program Files... It's honestly frustraiting

Comment: Yeha but again, what's stopping you from running the script in a user scope if you're using Invoke-Command or just using a variable to for the username? `$username = "test"; Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Write-Output "User: $username";}`. Also you don't need to create a psdrive

Comment: The short and sweet of my issue is that we have a central location. But corporate doesn't give us permission to network to it with scripts. We also can't doublehop, we are stuck using Kerberos, and even so simple as requesting Credentials twice(one to remote, once again to create a psdrive to a networkshare,) it fails, because once we are on the desktop, it can't validate any credentials we input against our AD. Running it as Admin flatout fails, because we cannot change the execution policy.

Comment: If I try it in the user's scope, then I wont have permission to access the Registry nor their Program Files - it has to be elevated with my own or anyone else who would use my tool

Comment: Taking a look again at your suggestion, I think I can figure out a way to do this. It's probably going to be gross, but at this point they gave me a task with both arms tied to do so, access wise

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. You might want expand your question and give an idea about what you're actually doing/code looks like. If you remote using RDP (as implied by the tag) you can use whatever credentials you want to start other applications (as you're doing). Using Invoke-Command with credentials only makes sense if there is an actual reason for it. If you are running the script with different credentials there doesn't seem to be. Changing execution policy is always possible, just not on the global scope.

Comment: Manually defining a user's location based on inputting their username did the trick, as for alt credentials, a lot of security policies get in the way of what is normal basic actions anyone should be able to do. I had to use elevated credentials to get the job done, but I puzzled it out in the end. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Get the location of the script with `$PSScriptRoot` in the script. Alternativley use `Enter-PSSession` to enter an interactive session and work manually.